# Linux stdout extract data beyond scroll view

Tags: linux

Is it possible to see beyond the scroll view the stdout that my program spat to the terminal?

I ran a program which spits a lot of output, I can only scroll up to see some amount of data. How can I see more data? Without having to rerun the program?

I cannot re-run the program so please don,t advice that option.

Thanks,
Chahat

Comment: Pipe the program's output into `less` or some other pager, e.g. `myprogram | less`. You'll be able to scroll up and down in the whole output. You might want to redirect the standard error output to the standard output beforehand, e.g. `myprogram 2>&1 | less`. Note that this question would have been more relevant on the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Aaron I cannot re/run the code. I said that already in the question.The program runs for a week and its not a choice to re run it at this moment

Comment: Sorry, I thought that might be useful for next time (that said the natural solution for a program running for a week would be to pipe its output to a file, not a pager). AFAIK it's not possible to retrieve output that has gone beyond the terminal's buffer, but I really think you should ask on the Unix&Linux SE, if anyone has a solution that'll be the fine folks there.

Comment: Got it.. thanks a lot for your help @Aaron .. Yeah i should have piped the output but looking for a redemption mechanism now.. thanks